# Add parameters to default profile in terminator

Tags: gnome-terminator

I would like to have some options which are not present in the GUI preferences of Terminator, such as
`force_no_bell = True`.
I want them to be set even for the default profile. But whenever I set it, and restart, 
Terminator sets the profile back to defaults (i.e `force_no_bell = False`).

My `terminator.config` is all defaults except some flashy colors.

```
$uname -a
Linux TUXBOX 3.15.8-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 1 08:51:42 CEST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$pacman -Q terminator
terminator 0.97-2
```